# CSS inset box-shadow with offset?

Tags: css

My desired outcome is a headline element with a thick underline that is slightly offset from the left like so:

[image]

I'm getting the underline to work with an inset CSS box-shadow, but I have no idea on how to offset it from the left so that it's not completely inline with the start of the h2 text.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  // -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  // -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

h2 span {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.0rem 0 0 #88DEB2;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Incredible Pure Castile Soap</span></h2>
```

Happy for any hints on how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try using `:before` (or `:after`) element?

Comment: Do you mean instead of the 'span' element or on the span? Sorry, but I'm having dificulties grasping the concept of :before and :after :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost good, simply add a negative `text-indent`:

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

h2 span {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.0rem 0 0 #88DEB2;
  display:inline-block; /* this is needed for the trick */
  text-indent: -1rem; /* here */
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Incredible Pure Castile Soap</span></h2>
```

A multiline solution with gradient

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

h2 span {
  background:
    linear-gradient(#88DEB2,#88DEB2) 
    bottom right/calc(100% - 1rem) 1rem 
    no-repeat;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Incredible Pure Castile Soap</span></h2>
```

Comment: Simple & Sweet!

Comment: @Temani Afif: Thanks for your answer. How would you implement line-break into your solution? The h2 span should break the line and the underline should remain also in the second line. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Thx for the swift reply, but this just removed the negative indent on the left, but still no line-break :/

Comment: @PhilippLaurim did you check the second snippet?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes and I see that it's working here in the snippet but already tried it out in my code and there it's not showing the desired behaviour

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry I accidentially left "width: max-content;" on the h2. Now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the pseudo element `::after` or `::before` and control the offset/positioning using left or right. Code explained in comments.

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  // -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  // -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  width: max-content; /* Take the content width */
}

h2 span::after {
  content: " "; /* Let us 'activate' the pseudo element */
  display: block; 
  background: #88DEB2;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -10px;
  left: 5px; /* Control the misalignment */
  z-index: -1; /* So that it appears underneath */
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Incredible Pure Castile Soap</span></h2>
```

Comment: How do you handle line breaks with your solution? In case of a line break the underline should continue on the second line.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the underline on both the 1st and 2nd line? Then you may have to use two separate elements. https://web-platform-7gxixd.stackblitz.io

Comment: ok thanks - this is not feasable with the cms that I'm using. It dynamically inserts one element with the title.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `linear-gradient` to fake an underline which should achieve this (see comments in code for details)

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  // -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  // -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h2 {
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

h2 span {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #88DEB2 50%); /* makes a linear gradient */
    background-position: 5px 0; /* offsets it */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* stops it from repeating */
    padding-right: 5px; /* gives more space for the underline offset */
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Incredible Pure Castile Soap</span></h2>
```